# Zsh: Creating associative array from yaml file using yq

Tags: yaml, zsh, associative-array, yq

The real case:

Every time I set up my environment, I'd like to check and – create if are not existing – certain environment variables. So, instead of doing it manually all the time, I thought it would be great if I can have a file which stores the environment name `env_N` and environment value `env_V` pairs. Amongst all text file formats, the `yaml` looks the simplest and the more natural to store that info.

So what I thought it would be great if I suck in the `yaml` file with my environmental variables using `yq` and create associative array ready to be iterated over by `zsh` `foreach` loop:

```
foreach entry in my_assoc_arr
do
  check_and_create(entry.env_N, entry.env_V)
done
```

with the final result of:

```
$ echo $env_N1
env_V1
$ echo $env_N2
env_V2
$ echo $env_N3
env_V3
...
```

The problem I'm having is to get my `yaml` to associative array using `yq` in shell `zsh` script.

After applying each suggestion from the comments, I was unable to create my associative array from `yaml` with `yq`. I had errors from `yq` like *bad syntax* or script worked or not depends on whether I have `#!/bin/zsh` switched on or commented out.

I got impression that my task is simple, but somehow I cant achieve this.

What I'm doing wrong here?

PS: I'm using `zsh` on macOS

Comment: => as a first approach to the subject: `for v in $(yq -r .[] data.yml); do echo $v; done`.

Comment: @Zeitounator: hmm, what about key value? And the assoc table? and also I realised the your solution doesn't work when I have '#!/usr/bin/env zsh` preamble in my script. Why is that?

Comment: Hmmm, What about a [mre] so that we exactly no what is the expected result?

Comment: Use a different language. `zsh`, in general, isn't suited towards the type of data typically encoded in YAML.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `zsh` for this? There is no reserved word `foreach` in `zsh` and shell function calls do not use `(`parentheses`)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to set environment variables through a Yaml, when it’s much easier to do it in a simple shell script?

Simply create a text file with the following line for each env var:

```
export FOO=bar
```

Then `source` this file from your shell or another shell script.

Comment: Firstly thank you for the suggestion. I definitely look towards your solution.
My justification towards my definition of the problem:
1. yaml looks for me as the simplest standardized container (amongst xml, json, ini) to store that information and to be sucked in directly to the associative tables,
2. I might use the same yaml file on Win system too
3. I might use the solution with associative tables to iterate over other pairs (not only the environmental variables)

Comment: You’re free to use whatever tool you like to generate the shell script that sets the env vars. However, trying to read Yaml from the shell is just making things needlessly complicated.

Comment: Here is a use case.  You want to write a cli tool (for `zsh` specifically).  For convenience, and because it's a `zsh` specific tool, you would prefer to use as much pure `zsh` as possible.  But you want to have an easily accessible and powerful configuration language like yaml.  So it would be great to have a generalized way of reading yaml into bash easily.

Comment: `bash` supports the same `export` statements as `zsh`. You can `source` the same file from `bash`.